# Save UIBezierPath in SQLite

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I am drawing freehand annotation over a view using UIBezierPath. And I want to save it in SQLite to draw over a view when user open that view. Is there any way to save UIBezierPath in SQLite, so I can use it any time to draw over view.

Comment: You should save your data related to drawing not UIBezierPath.

Comment: you could serialize it to data since it conforms to NSCoding

Answer (score 3):

You could serialize it to data (in the form of an *NSData* instance) since *UIBezierPath* conforms to *NSCoding* (i.e.

```
NSData * data = [NSData archivedDataWithRootObject:yourPath]
```

Another option might be to convert to/from SVG and save that.

Answer (score 1):

You could save all control points of a `UIBezierPath` instead of saving the path directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize/deserialize `UIBezierPath` by defining a path model and using Codable. While making attributes like `lineWidth` or `lineCapStyle` as `Codable` is trivial, the code for path elements (stored in `UIBezierPath.cgPath`) is more complex. However, here is a starting point:

```
enum PathElement: Codable, Equatable {
    case moveToPoint(CGPoint)
    case addLineToPoint(CGPoint)
    case addQuadCurveToPoint(controlPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint)
    case addCurveToPoint(controlPoint1: CGPoint, controlPoint2: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint)
    case closeSubpath
}

extension CGPath {
    static func pathFromPathElements(_ pathElements: [PathElement]) -> CGPath {
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        for pathElement in pathElements {
            switch pathElement {
            case .moveToPoint(let point):
                path.move(to: point)
            case .addLineToPoint(let point):
                path.addLine(to: point)
            case .addQuadCurveToPoint(let controlPoint, let endPoint):
                path.addQuadCurve(to: endPoint, control: controlPoint)
            case .addCurveToPoint(let controlPoint1, let controlPoint2, let endPoint):
                path.addCurve(to: endPoint, control1: controlPoint1, control2: controlPoint2)
            case .closeSubpath:
                path.closeSubpath()
            }
        }
        return path
    }

    func pathElements() -> [PathElement] {
        var result = [PathElement]()

        applyWithBlock { elementPointer in
            let element = elementPointer.pointee
            switch element.type {
            case .moveToPoint:
                let points = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: element.points, count: 1))
                let el = PathElement.moveToPoint(points[0])
                result.append(el)
            case .addLineToPoint:
                let points = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: element.points, count: 1))
                let el = PathElement.addLineToPoint(points[0])
                result.append(el)
            case .addQuadCurveToPoint:
                let points = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: element.points, count: 2))
                let el = PathElement.addQuadCurveToPoint(
                    controlPoint: points[0], endPoint: points[1])
                result.append(el)
            case .addCurveToPoint:
                let points = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: element.points, count: 3))
                let el = PathElement.addCurveToPoint(
                    controlPoint1: points[0], controlPoint2: points[1], endPoint: points[2])
                result.append(el)
            case .closeSubpath:
                result.append(.closeSubpath)
            @unknown default:
                fatalError()
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```